# Disable http timeout in the Firefox 29.0

Tags: firefox

How to disable timeout in Firefox 29.0 / Ubuntu 14.04?

I have some web scripts that need time (up to 30 minutes) to complete.

```
The connection has timed out

The server at ... is taking too long to respond.
```

I tried to change `network.http.connection-timeout` to 99999 but timeout message still pops up after 1-2 minutes...

In previous version (28.0? not sure...) firefox used to wait forever which was OK for me (there was no need to change config)

Currently I run my scripts using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) but executing scripts in proper net browser was way more convenient for me.

Comment: Why not tweak the scripts to produce some initial output? The key to resolving this is to acknowledge the request was received.

Comment: @DanielB I would rather like to stick with wget

Comment: "I would rather like to stick with wget" ... "but executing scripts in proper net browser was way more convenient for me."  So which is it that you want?  To keep using WGET, or to have it work properly with a browser?

Comment: @techie007: I want firefox to have no timeout, as asked in the question. I really do know workarounds (simple bash script with wget is one I currently use)

Comment: Is a browser really the best way to access this page?  Wouldn't curl/wget be better?

Comment: @Zoredache it was just nice for me, I had bookmark folder with few scripts, also I could review the and manage results in browser etc. I can live without it, I just wonder is it possible to get it back in firefox 29. I currently use proxy script which outputs hello text as workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [list of changes between version 28 and 29](https://cat-in-136.blogspot.de/2014/03/diff-between-firefox-290-beta-3-default.html#1052678216882915160) the key `network.http.response.timeout` was set to `300`. Try to change it to something higher.

Ben Morgen [wrote](https://morgb.blogspot.de/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html) in his blog that this would work.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks! I am able to start scripts in firefox again!

Answer (score -1):

OK... at a guess,

open a new tab and go to about:config

Click "I'll be careful, I Promise".

Change the 
dom.max_chrome_script_run_time and dom.max_script_run_time to unlimited

Restart Firefox and see if this works for you.  Remember to make a note of the old settings and you may want to revert this if it doesn't work.  I've just tried it and I've had a recursive pointless loop running for a couple of minutes on my box without timing out.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think these settings are for javascript, preventing firefox to hang... I want to run 30-minutes long server side scripts, no javascript at all